# Best practice to save changes of a RecyclerView list item when using MVVM and LiveData?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture) to understand how to use `LiveData` and data binding to update the UI when changes occur in the database and also save data back to the database when I make changes in the app.

The part I'm missing is how to properly extend the things explained in the guide to a `Layout`with a `RecyclerView`. In this case, the `ViewModel` would contain a `LiveData<List<Model>> models` member and I would have to bind a `RecyclerView` list item  to a `Model`, by adding something like this in my list item `<layout/>`:

```
<data>
    <variable name="model"
        type="com.example.models.Model" />
</data>
```

but still observe the `models` colletion of my `ViewModel` in my `Activity`:

```
viewModel.models.observe(this, Observer { models ->
    modelsAdapter.data = models?.data
    modelsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
})
```

The `Observer`'s method above will not be triggered if a property of a `Model` instance in the `models` collection changes so If I want to run some code (like saving data to my DB) when a change is made by the user on a list item which is bound to my `Model`, I could just add a method to my `Model` class and bind the `onChange` event of a `View` in my list item `<layout/>` to that method. Let's say that I'd have an `EditText` on my list item `<layout/>`, then I could add the lines below to run the the `listItemTextChanged()` method on the bound `Model` when the text on my `EditText` changes:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="@={model.ListItemText}"
    android:onTextChanged="@{ () -> model.listItemTextChanged()}" />
```

However, this means that beside adding a method to my `Model` class I'd also have to add a reference to my `Repository` if I want to save the text of my `EditText` to the database and it feels like this is not the correct way to do it and that my `ViewModel`, which contains the `LiveData<List<Model>> models` should be responsible for communicating with my `Repository` to perform database operations.

I know that I could add the `ViewModel` as a `<layout/>` variable to my list item `<layout/>` and add a `listItemTextChanged(Model model)` method on my `ViewModel` that could then update the `model` in the database but that doesn't sound right either.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

i dont use databinding however your quite right that only the view model should talk to the repository, but if your using live data then you need to observe it in your fragment /activity and that should update your recycler view

```
myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
    myViewModel.getCards().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new 
        Observer<List<Card>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Card> cards) {
            if (cards != null && cardAdapter != null){
                    cardAdapter.refreshList(cards);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

so you could add a text watcher on the card and have that call a method in your view model to save it although that would probably update too much, maybe have a save button

Comment: I'm already observing the models of my ViewModel, I edited my question so it specifies this too. I'm hoping for an answer that would make use of data binding, but your answer is a valid option too